# Adjust p-values for multiple comparisons

Tags: classification, p-value, bagging, adjustment

I want to evaluate if a proposed modification **M*** to a base classifier **M** is better in terms of accuracy. Both, the base classifiers **M** and their respective modifications **M*** are tested on *N* datasets.

To make it more specific, the base classifier **M** could be a decision tree, naive bayes, knn, etc. And the modified model is a set of *n* base classifiers which are trained by sampling the training set with replacement (bagging). For example, if **M1** is a decision tree then **M1*** will be a set of decision trees and each tree will produce a prediction and the final output will be the majority voting of all predictions. (In this case the modification consists of aggregating the results of the given base classifier, but this was just to make a concrete example. The modification could be anything else that depends on the same base classifier).

Each dataset **D** is evaluated using 10 fold cross validation using different base classifiers and their respective modification. A paired t-test is used to evaluate the mean accuracy over the 10 folds between each base classifier **M** and its modification **M***. The resulting p-values can be visualized in a matrix as shown below:

[image]

Since I am doing multiple comparisons I need to adjust the p-values.

> The question is:

Should the p-values adjustment be done by rows, columns or both?

The 3 cases are listed below assuming a Bonferroni correction, i.e., p-value * number of comparisons.

1. **By rows:** In this case the correction for the row M1/M1* would be to multiply p1,1, p1,2 and p1,3 by 3. And do the same for each row.
2. **By columns:** Multiply each element of column **D1** by 4 and do the same for **D2** and **D3**
3. **By both:** Multiply every p-value by 12.

For me, doing it by columns does not make sense. So I am between by rows or by both.